# Insert into taking extremely long

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I'm currently working with a Microsoft SQL Server 2017 instance.

I have a java script program that is building insert into statements based on some logic then executing them one by one.

For some reason the insert into statements are taking ages to run, in some cases 30s per insert.

But on average its more akin to 10-11 ms per insert.

I'm not sure but this seems pretty slow to me? I had been using a postgresql DB for the same workload that was taking about 2.5ms per record.

The table is quite large in number of records and number of fields. (it was slow even when the table was empty) the table is now at 20 million+ records.

Below is an example of one of the insert into statements:

```
INSERT INTO mipbi_ods.test_table (
    "field1"
    ,"field2"
    ,"field3"
    ,"field4"
    ,"field5"
    ,"field6"
    ,"field7"
    ,"field8"
    ,"field9"
    ,"field10"
    ,"field11"
    ,"field12"
    ,"field13"
    ,"field14"
    ,"field15"
    ,"field16"
    ,"field17"
    ,"field18"
    ,"field19"
    ,"field20"
    ,"field21"
    ,"field22"
    ,"field23"
    ,"field24"
    ,"field25"
    ,"field26"
    ,"field27"
    ,"field28"
    ,"field29"
    ,"field30"
    ,"field31"
    ,"field32"
    ,"field33"
    ,"field34"
    ,"field35"
    ,"field36"
    ,"field37"
    ,"field38"
    ,"field39"
    ,"field40"
    ,"field41"
    ,"field42"
    ,"field43"
    ,"field44"
    ,"field45"
    ,"field46"
    ,"field47"
    ,"field48"
    ,"field49"
    ,"field50"
    ,"field51"
    ,"field52"
    ,"field53"
    ,"field54"
    ,"field55"
    ,"field56"
    ,"field57"
    ,"field58"
    ,"field59"
    ,"field60"
    ,"field61"
    ,"field62"
    ,"field63"
    ,"field64"
    ,"field65"
    ,"field66"
    ,"field67"
    ,"field68"
    ,"field69"
    ,"field70"
    ,"field71"
    ,"field72"
    ,"field73"
    ,"field74"
    ,"field75"
    ,"field76"
    ,"field77"
    ,"field78"
    ,"field79"
    ,"field80"
    ,"field81"
    ,"field82"
    ,"field83"
    ,"field84"
    ,"field85"
    ,"field86"
    ,"field87"
    ,"field88"
    ,"field89"
    ,"field90"
    ,"field91"
    ,"field92"
    ,"field93"
    ,"field94"
    ,"field95"
    ,"field96"
    ,"field97"
    ,"field98"
    ,"field99"
    ,"field100"
    ,"field101"
    ,"field102"
    ,"field103"
    ,"field104"
    ,"field105"
    ,"field106"
    ,"field107"
    ,"field108"
    ,"field109"
    ,"field110"
    ,"field111"
    ,"field112"
    ,"field113"
    ,"field114"
    ,"field115"
    ,"field116"
    ,"field117"
    ,"field118"
    ,"field119"
    ,"field120"
    ,"field121"
    ,"field122"
    ,"field123"
    )
VALUES (
    NULL
    ,CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, '2019/12/14 06:27:48.868+02:00', 121)
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,3
    ,'190SZ89M'
    ,32
    ,'3023456'
    ,390496
    ,CONVERT(DATE, '2019/08/22', 23)
    ,'000594'
    ,'69840896'
    ,1
    ,'Yeah'
    ,73.21
    ,99
    ,'C'
    ,73.21
    ,0
    ,0
    ,100
    ,'D'
    ,NULL
    ,'M11'
    ,CONVERT(DATE, '2019/08/22', 23)
    ,'RT'
    ,CONVERT(DATE, '2019/08/25', 23)
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,40
    ,NULL
    ,'HHHH'
    ,NULL
    ,0
    ,45535671
    ,171
    ,390496
    ,390496
    ,0
    ,0
    ,0
    ,0
    ,CONVERT(DATE, '2019/08/22', 23)
    ,0
    ,6034284
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,0
    ,60
    ,73.21
    ,0
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,0
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,0
    ,'CodecodesradfdgdfgdfgZ76.9dfgdfgdfg08/22/2019dfgdfhd60noteM11dfgsedf99dfgdfgdfgCdfgdfgd?dfgdfgdfg?dfgdfgdfgdg?sdfsdfsdfsdf?sdfsdfsdfs?sdfsdfsdf?sfsdfs?sdfsdfsd?sdfsdfsf?sdfsgfghhf?dfdfsde171'
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,CONVERT(DATETIME, '2019/08/22 15:41:03.357', 121)
    ,NULL
    ,0
    ,604
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,0
    ,0
    ,0
    ,0
    ,0
    ,0
    ,0
    ,0
    ,0
    ,0
    ,0
    ,0
    ,0
    ,0
    ,0
    ,0
    ,0
    ,0
    ,0
    ,0
    ,NULL
    ,'*'
    ,978443465
    ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ,'CURRENT'
    ,NULL
    ,'hdfsd'
    ,dbo.global_sequence()
    ,NULL
    ,'dfgdfgdfg'
    );
```

Here is the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[global_sequence] () RETURNS INT BEGIN RETURN (SELECT number_i_need.sequence FROM schema1.number_i_need) END GO
```

Here is my query execution plan, this seems like a lot for a basic insert?

[Query execution plan:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMvTc.png)

Comment: What indexes, and triggers, do you have on your table? What is your `CLUSTERED INDEX`? Is the value always ascending when performing your inserts?

Comment: Also, there's a Scalar function referenced in that `INSERT` (`dbo.global_sequence`). User Scalar functions are notoriously slow, depending on their usage (2019 does off inline for Scalar functions, which does significantly improve them). The fact that it doesn't take an input parameter as well seems odd. What is its purpose? What is the DDL of that function? Why use a Scalar function, when it accepts no input parameter?

Comment: One way of trying to find the problem is to look at the execution plan if you can. Trigger actions or other 'problems' could become apparant through them.

Comment: Having a field1 to field123 also seems to point out that you have to normalize your db. Especially since most of the values are 'null' or '0'.

Comment: @Larnu I have no triggers on the table. 
I have no clustered index, but i have 5 non-clustered indexes none with more than 3 fields in it. 
The time taken is consistent around 11ms it did jump to 12ms on occasion.
The purpose of the dbo.global_sequence function is just to retrieve a value from another table. Its just a select value from table and returns the current value in that table. That table is a single field table with a number that we increment with an update statement when we need to call the function. (I hope that made sense?). Im not sure why its that function im new to this.

Comment: Im happy to have alternate options there. 

@Carra The fields are named 1-123 for obfuscation reasons. The data is very random those nulls are just a random line i picked.

Comment: @DKramer Forgive me for being so noob here, how does one do that on SSMS? I'm from the postgres side of things so im still learning :) Found it online thanks!

Comment: *"That table is a single field table with a number that we increment with an update statement when we need to call the function."* That sounds suspicious. How are you handling concurrency issues with that table?

Comment: @Larnu So how i was managing this was, before every call to get the current value,  i would run the update statement. So it would increment only the moment before i get the value.

Comment: As long as your table definition will use default NULL for any fields then you only have to supply the fields in your insert where the value is NOT NULL.  Since you have a lot of NULL's this will cut down on the SQL parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions. @Larnu especially for making me look into my function.  I've managed to get around my issue.

I found the cause of the slow insert to be, the user defined function i had in my insert statement. I then moved to using a sequence, which was a lot better but still a bit slow.

I then came across "[rowversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)" which is a binary value and not legible but can be ordered so that works great. It can also be applied to all my existing records in the DB without needing to reinsert those or update them.

My inserts are now in the region of 1.9ms to insert the record. Not super amazing but good enough for my purposes, considering the number of columns.